# How to match String with regex in this case?

Tags: regex, string

I have get a set of Strings with pattern like:

```
category=50025969&city=%CE%C2%D6%DD&auction_start_seg=-1
```

now I wish to extract all substrings like:

```
city=%CE%C2%D6%DD
```

How can I write a regex to express that?

Comment: Which language are you using?. Also, what ahve you tried?

Comment: I'm using Java and I just used IndexOf() to find that but it is not very useful in this case, I don't know much about how to use regex right now

Comment: Also I tried (city=.*?)& or (city=.*?), but the first one get a "&"left and second can only get"city="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a lot of possible regex to answer your question. Here is mine:

`(?=city=)[^&]*`

gives you `city=VALUE` where match starts in `city=` until it finds a `&` char.